# Callback from background to content script after tab url changed

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, tabs

I am new to chrome extensions and I am facing a problem.
I run a script when my extension's icon is clicked :

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) { 
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        "file": "enterIonis.js"
    });
});
```

This script gets some informations from the opened tab, then changes the tab url to load a new page. This script then needs to wait for the new page to be fully loaded to interact with it. For that it opens a port and sends a message to the background page which uses the `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener. The background page **should** send a message/callback to the content script to tell it that it's now ok to interact with the tab.

*background.js :*

```
var _port;
var goodUrl;


chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
  console.assert(port.name == "enterIonis");
  port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
        goodUrl = msg.url;
        _port = port; 
    });
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function ( tabId, changeInfo, tab ){ 
  if ( changeInfo.status === "complete" ){

    chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'lastFocusedWindow': true}, function (tabs) {
        var currentUrl = tab.url;
        if(currentUrl == goodUrl){
            //should send a callback to content script here
            _port.postMessage({result: "ok"});
        }
    }); 

  }
});
```

*content_script.js*

```
//interacting with DOM elements
...

// sending a message to background.js
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name: "enterIonis"});
port.postMessage({url:href});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg){
    // here is where the message from the background telling the tab is ready should arrive
    alert(msg.result);
});
```

The problem is that when I try to use the port from the first message, I get the following error : `Error in response to tabs.query: Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object`

How can I re-connect the port ? Or is there any other way to achieve my goal ?

Comment: It's not clear why you can't do your manipulation from the background script instead of injecting a script into the page and having to set up communication.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: While you have supplied enough so we can make a good **guess** as to what is *likely* happening, without you including a *complete* [mcve] in the question, we can not know if the guess is correct.

Comment: @pvg  I need content scripts to interact with DOM elements that are on the page

Answer (score 1):

### [`tabs.executeScript()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-executeScript) injects into the *page*, not persistently into a tab

You will have to separately inject a content script into the new page. Injecting a script using `tabs.executeScript()` does not inject a script into a tab which persists for the tab across loading of new web pages. It injects a script into the *page* which is currently displayed in the specified tab. Once that page is no longer displayed in that tab, the content script no longer exists.

You say your script "changes the tab url to load a new page", and then is supposed to do other things, which it doesn't do. As soon as the new page begins loading, the context for the content script you injected is destroyed along with the context for the old web page. Your content script can not send a message to your background script once the new page loads, because your content script no longer exists.

Comment: Alright I understand now, I thought I could use content scripts as classes. But then how should I do ? Because I don't want to have a big switch case in my `chrome.tabs.onUpdated` listener telling which script to execute according to the current tab url... I would like something more dynamic

Comment: @DavidSeroussi, It is hard to make suggestions without more information as to what you are wanting to do. Your two basic options of how to inject scripts are *manifest,json* `content_scripts` entries, which are statically defined within the extension, and `tabs.executeScript()` which is dynamic, but usually comes with more complexity.

Comment: Basically, I want to : find certain DOM elements on a page, interact with them, load a new page (according to those previous elements), and repeat the process until a certain condition is filled. To interact with DOM elements I have to use content scripts, but I also need the page to be fully loaded (that's why I use the background page). I thought I could use messaging to communicate between those content scripts and the background page.

Comment: @DavidSeroussi, I still really don't know enough about what you are doing to make concrete suggestions.  However, it sounds like you could repeatedly inject the same content script into the tab using `tabs.executeScript()` until such time as your content script determines it is done. Once it determines it is done, it messages the background script to turn off the injections into every new page. If the content script needs info from the background script to make choices, or vise versa, then that info can be messaged back and forth.

Comment: My extension will run on a single website. This website contains multiple pages, and the extension basically navigates through these pages to find a video, and to launch it. When the video ends, it starts searching for a new video and the cycle repeats itself.  I can not always inject the same script in all the pages since there are 5-6 different types of pages. And the pages' URLs are contained in DOM elements.

Comment: @DavidSeroussi, It sounds like you will need to be injecting scripts into multiple pages. The choice between one larger script that does multiple different things and multiple scripts which do limited things is largely going to depend on if most of your logic is going to be in the content script or in the background script. Without significantly more detail it is difficult to make a suggestion as to which would be better.